# How does Hinduism refute the idea that knowledge is impossible?

Tags: belief, brahman, knowledge

How does Hinduism refute epistemological skepticism? I am really inclined to know more about Hinduism, Brahman, etc. which interest me a lot however even if one feels or realizes what the Brahman is, or realize their true-self, or whatever beliefs are included, how does one refute the idea "that knowledge is impossible" and that maybe it is not a deception or something else in the context of Hinduism , any strong argument from the scriptures, anywhere is welcome.